# Is there a way to combine more than one type for typing

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Using the type hinting library `typing` is it possible to combine two types? I would like to have either a single `str` or a `list of str` for the parameters. see below:

```
from typing import Dict, Optional, List


def run_ml(
        estimator: Estimator,
        parameters: Optional[Dict[str, List[str]]] = None,
):
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can use [Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union).

Example

```
def send_email(address: Union[str, List[str]],
               sender: str,
               cc: Optional[List[str]],
               bcc: Optional[List[str]],
               subject='',
               body: Optional[List[str]] = None
               ) -> bool:
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [typing.Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union)
like this `Union[List[str], str]`